# OverloadDefinitions on CSV field?

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

I [created a question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606904/saving-csv-columns-to-array) where I asked how to save a specific CSV column into a PowerShell array. I got my question answered and my passwords and my usernames are now saved in two different arrays. However, the Server IP-Adresses doesn't want to be saved into the array I made for them to be saved in. When I try to log in to a server (with PowerShell inputting credentials automatically) I get this error:

```
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to
pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of
strings.
At C:xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\pornfolder:37 char:15
+ ...   $output = Invoke-Command -computername $AddressArray[$row] -credent ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

So I printed the array where the adresses are meant to be saved in, and I get this:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Address(int )
```

This is, honest to god, all that is saved in the array. No wonder the computername(s) are invalid.

Here is the code

```bsh
$PasswordsArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$UsernamesArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$Importedcsv = Import-csv "C:\my\csv\file\is\located.here" -Delimiter ";"

$PasswordsArray += @($Importedcsv.password)
$AA += [string] @($Importedcsv.address)
$UsernamesArray += @($Importedcsv.username)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your issue is caused by a convenience feature that was introduced in PowerShell v3 combined with awkward field naming. Since PowerShell v3 arrays are automatically unrolled when you use dot-notation on them (`$arr.something`). That way properties or methods can be called on the array elements via the array object without having to loop over the elements (`$arr | ForEach-Object {$_.something}`).

Your column title (`address`) conflicts with the name of a method of the array object (`Address()`).

```
PS C:\> $Importedcsv | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
address     NoteProperty System.String address=192.168.0.10
password    NoteProperty System.String password=#adfgad
username    NoteProperty System.String username=advokathuset\user

PS C:\> Get-Member -InputObject $Importedcsv

   TypeName: System.Object[]

Name           MemberType            Definition
----           ----------            ----------
Count          AliasProperty         Count = Length
Add            Method                int IList.Add(System.Object value)
Address        Method                System.Object&, mscorlib, Versio...
Clear          Method                void IList.Clear()
...
```

`$Importedcsv | Get-Member` unrolls the array (via the pipeline), so `Get-Member` is called on the array elements, whereas `Get-Member -InputObject $Importedcsv` operates on the array object itself (PowerShell imports CSVs as an array of objects).

Rename the column to something else, either at the source (where you create the file), or on import:

```
$filename = "C:\my\csv\file\is\located.here"
$headers  = 'IPAddress', 'Username', 'Password'

$Importedcsv = Import-Csv $filename -Delimiter ";" -Header $headers

$AA = @($Importedcsv.IPAddress)
```

or expand the `address` property on the individual array items in a loop:

```
$AA = @($Importedcsv | ForEach-Object { $_.address } )
```

Note that a construct `[string]@(...)` will cast your array to a single string, so don't use it unless you actually want all addresses in a single string. To enforce a string array you'd use `[string[]]@(...)`, but usually that's not necessary with PowerShell, so I'd recommend against using it unless you know what you need it for.

Also note that it's unnecessary to create an `ArrayList` object and append to it. The `@()` operator will already produce an array, so you should simplify things like this:

```
$PasswordsArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$PasswordsArray += @($Importedcsv.password)
```

to this:

```
$PasswordsArray = @($Importedcsv.password)
```

unless you require specific features of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ansgar, I read this through with a colleague. I'll come back to you asap. :)

Comment: The name of this convenience feature is "property enumeration"